# What is this defining

Tags: c, constants

I found this code in the Atmel Mega 2560 manual.

```
#define FOSC 1843200// Clock Speed
#define BAUD 9600
#define (MYUBRR FOSC/16/BAUD-1)
```

I'm wondering what the third #define does. I think the first one is the processor speed and the second one is the baud rate, which all makes sense. I can't figure the third one out.

In the sample code, it uses `MYUBRR` like it was a compiler constant, but what does it mean that it's preceded by a `(`?

Comment: looks like a typo. guessing it should be `#define MYUBRR (FOSC/16/BAUD-1)`, and from there there's plenty info on why macro results should be parenthesised to avoid horror.

Comment: The manual has syntax errors. (And the first macro is made unusable by the comment.)

Comment: I wondered that. Gosh, a typo in the manual...

Comment: Where is that manual? All the references I can find have a properly written macro

Comment: @EugeneSh. This one has the code as in the question: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-2549-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf. Seems like a typo.

Comment: @nielsen Thanks. Yeah, it is frustrating how the HW vendors neglecting the proper SW side in their manuals/reference codes.